# XPath is returning element including the tags

Tags: xpath, querypath

I am using xPath to read an XML file, but when trying to get the contents of a certain element, it returns it including the tags <> .

The XML file is structured like this:

```
<item>
    <attribute01>something</attribute01>
    <attribute02>something</attribute02>
    <attribute03>something</attribute03>
    <attribute04>
        <category>Some category name</category>
        <category>Some other category name</category>
    </attribute04>
</item>
```

I am working in the context of //item and then using attribute04//category to get the category element. However, this is what I'm getting back:

```
xpathparser:04 :
<Category>Bed &amp; Breakfast and Inns</Category>
xpathparser:04 :
<Category>Hotel</Category>
...etc...
```

It returns the entire element including the tags. Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong here?

I am using the Feeds xPath parser module for Drupal (https://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the XPath, and the code which invokes it and uses the result. XPath is probably doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: @keshlam is right: if you select the `category` you get the node including tags. If you just want the text try `attribute04/category/text()` or `string(attribute04/category)`.

Comment: Thank you both. That worked. Didn't realize I had to use text(), cause it worked without it for other attributes. How do I mark your comments as the answer?

Comment: There's an answer now that you can pick... :-)

Comment: It might work in some cases because of the the way your host language deals with the data. Your API might convert nodes to their string value automatically. In strict DOM implementations you might have to do things like `evaluate(attribute04/category)->item(0)->nodeValue` to extract the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select the text portion of a node in an XPath expression you have to use the `text()` function as follows:

```
attribute04/category/text()
```

The expression

```
attribute04/category
```

will select the XML node instead resulting in the output of the bracings tags and the text.