# Select xml element using attribute value

Tags: php, xpath

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<error>
<error_detail code="0">Successfully</error_detail>
<error_detail code="1">Invalid Username or Password</error_detail>
<error_detail code="2">No username or password</error_detail>
<error_detail code="3">Session has expired</error_detail>
<error_detail code="4">Date of effectivity cannot be less than</error_detail>
</error>
```

How can I get the "session has expired" using xpath?

I tried:

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$a     = $xml->xpath("//error_detail[@code='3']");
display_output($a);
```

I am getting this instead:

```
array ( 0 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( '@attributes' => array ( 'code' => '53', ), )), )
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888679/xpath-is-returning-element-including-the-tags/23891383#23891383. Please upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath query returns an array even if the query returns just a single element. You need to convert this first element to string in order to obtain the text value:

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$a     = $xml->xpath("//error_detail[@code=3]");

// convert to string though . ''
var_dump($a[0] . ''); // string(19) "Session has expired"
```